# Need better algorithm for Sphere Online Judge's "FOODIES - ChickenLove" challenge

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve [Sphere Online Judge's "FOODIES - ChickenLove" problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FOODIES/). In this problem, there are *n* sets of the form { 1, 2, …, *A1* }, { 1, 2, …, *A2* }, …, { 1, 2, …, *An* }. (The input just contains the integers *A1*, *A2*, … *An*; the other elements of the sets are implied.) The goal of the problem is, for a given *m*, to find the maximum sum that you can get by choosing *m* distinct elements from these sets.

For example, given this input:

- *A1* = **3** (meaning that the first set is { 1, 2, 3 })
- *A2* = **5** (meaning that the second set is { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
- *A3* = **4** (meaning that the third set is { 1, 2, 3, 4 })
- *m* = **3** (meaning that we need to select three elements from these sets)

the desired result is 4 + 4 + 5 = **13**.

Currently I'm solving this with a priority queue, but I'm getting a "timeout" error (meaning that my solution takes too long). How can I optimize my solution? Is there a better approach?

**MY CURRENT APPROACH**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    int n,k,x;
    long long c=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        pq.push(x);
    }
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        int p=pq.top();
        c+=p;
        pq.push(p-1);
        pq.pop();

    }
   printf("%lld\n",c);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us *how* you're solving this with a priority queue. (A priority queue can certainly be *part* of an optimal solution to this problem, but it's not the whole solution.)

Comment: @ruakh I have updated.

Comment: It comes out to be O(mlogn) where m can be maximum 10^10

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Time Limit Exceeded because the maximum `M <= 10^10`, and your code's time complexity is `O(N + M log N)`.

This problem's constraints is `1 <= A[i] <= 100000`, so you can count the number of x's in the all set (in my code: the value is c[x]).

So, you only have to process this queries for `1 <= i <= N`. (initial value of c[i] = 0)

- Add 1 to the values c[1], c[2], c[3],..., c[A[i]].

You can process with naive algorithm for `O(M)`, and with cumulative-sum algorithm for `O(N)`.

If you count `c[1], c[2], ..., c[max(A[1], A[2],..., A[N])]`, you can do like my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int T, N; long long M;
int main() {
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--) {
        scanf("%d", &N);
        vector<int> A(N);
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        scanf("%lld", &M);
        int z = *max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
        vector<int> c(z + 2), s(z + 2);
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) s[1]++, s[A[i] + 1]--;
        for(int i = 1; i <= z; i++) c[i] = c[i - 1] + s[i];
        long long ret = 0;
        for(int i = z; i >= 1; i--) {
            if(M <= c[i]) {
                ret += 1LL * M * i; M = 0;
                break;
            }
            ret += 1LL * c[i] * i; M -= c[i];
        }
        printf("%lld\n", ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The overall time complexity is `O(N + max(A[1], A[2],..., A[N]))`.
I submitted to SPOJ and I got AC (0.20 sec) !